# Managing Heroku Multiple environments with existing app

Tags: heroku

I've got an app, that has 'heroku' configured as a remote, to one application.
Let's call this app 'MyAppDev'

However, I have another app, called 'MyAppLive'
I want to configure deployment like this:

> git push staging
>   push to MyAppDev
>
> git push production
>   push to MyAppLive

How can I do this?

Also, what about environment variables?
Both apps have MongoLab, so I'd like the MyAppDev app to use it's own db....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are the steps that you'd need to follow

1. `git remote rm heroku` - this will remove the heroku remote from your application
2. `git remote add production <production apps heroku git repo url>` - this will add a new remote named 'production' pointing at the production apps git repo url (you can get this from the My Apps page on heroku.com
3. `git remote add staging <staging apps heroku git repo url>`

This now means you can do `git push production master` or `git push staging master` to push your codebase to either repo.

*NOTE* If you need to push branches to Heroku you need to push them into the master branch of Heroku.

eg. assuming a staging branch locally you would do;

```
git push staging staging:master
```

To push your locally staging branch into master of the staging remote.

Any addons you use would need to be duplicated to the staging application.

Config variables can either be done manually via `heroku config:set` or you can use the plugin  detailed at the bottom of this page https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars which allows you to push and pull your Heroku variables into a .env file suitable for running with Foreman locally. Becareful about overriding variables though - I tend to do my variables manually as I don't typically have many.

Comment: Additionally, there's a pretty extensive article on this topic here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments. One tip is to do `git config heroku.staging` if you want to push to the staging app by default (saves you from having to type the `-r staging` every time).

Comment: good call Ryan - forgot about that one. My one at http://johnbeynon.posterous.com/developing-with-multiple-environments-on-hero is almost two years old now!! Wow how time flies :)